# Tilda becomes ± with bluetooth keyboard Keychron K2 in OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave, bluetooth

I want to type  `~/work` in iterm2 but somehow it becomes `±/work`. I am also unable type the inverted comma ` (the character shares the same key with tilda). It becomes §.

[image]

I am using a bluetooth keyboard (Keychron K2) with ANSI layout. I have already tried turning the keyboard on and off. I have also tried depressing the `Fn` key and other key combinations but there is no effect.

The keyboard has no such issue before.

The language is set to Australian

[image]

What is the likely cause of this issue? How can I fix it?

I am using a MacBookPro.

**Edit:**

1. Upon more testings, this is normally what I see in the System Preference.

[image]

However the moment I depressed a key, I can see the layout switched

[image]

2. The keyboard supports wired mode (see https://www.keychron.com/products/keychron-k2-wireless-mechanical-keyboard). If I connect the keyboard with the mac in wired mode, the problem went away
3. Before this problem appears, I have uninstalled Karabiner-Elements. I used Karabiner-Elements because I need it for other mechanical keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. Apply [the latest firmware](https://www.keychron.com/pages/special-firmware-for-k2) from the company 
   [image]
2. Install and use `Karabiner-Elements`

Comment: I'm here in 2022 with macOS 12.5.1, it shows "app is damaged" error for this firmware. I have to workaround this issue by using `xattr -cr K2-white-V1.6.app` (basically resets file metadata that have among other things security/integrity warnings for this app) from terminal, after that patching was successful and now I have my ` and ~

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your machine may think the keyboard is ISO instead of ANSI.  Some possible fixes for this problem can be found [here](https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html).

Comment: I think you are onto something. I have added more info in the question. Basically I find that my keyboard layout is switching when I pressed a key.

Comment: @AnthonyKong I think that shows your machine sees the internal keyboard correctly but sees the external one as iso instead of ansi.  Have you tried any of the fixes in the link?

Comment: I reran the keyboard setup assistant, and this was the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is just my theory (and also my first question to answer on here)
is the option key like being pushed constantly? on my JS layout keyboard if i just push the key its "^" and if i shift push it it's "~" and if i shift opt push it it's "±" so

Comment: But if the option key is stuck, this would not just affect one key, he would not be able to type anything correctly.  Also if you try using the Australian input source, like he uses, the option key does not produce ± on the backtik/tilde key.